# How to update or change table raw's values in javafx without making the table editable?

Tags: javafx, tableview

I am very much depressed trying many times to implement this but not successful yet.
I am trying to change a javafx table raw's particular value when a user change a button. Suppose if the table has a particular raw value is 10 then if user press a button the value will be changed to 20 but how can I do that?
But this simple technique is very much easy in java swing. Please some help me to do the same thing in javafx.

Comment: Perhaps this would help: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/javafx/tableview.html In particular, look at: lastNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("lastName"));

Comment: @Redwine - I'm afraid that has nothing to do with the OP's question...

Answer (score 4):

You do not update the value of a `TableCell` directly. Instead, modify the underlying data model values.

Take a look at what type of `List<>` you're passing to the `TableView` when you call `tableView.setItems()`.  It is that data type that you want to update.

For example, suppose you have a `TableView<Person>` that contains a `List` of `Person` objects:

```
public class Person {
    private final StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();
    private final StringProperty email = new SimpleStringtProperty();

    public Person (String name, String email) {
        this.name.set(name);
        this.email.set(email);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name.get();
    }

    public StringProperty nameProperty() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name.set(name);
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email.get();
    }

    public StringProperty emailProperty() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email.set(email);
    }
}
```

So you have your `List<Person>` and you've used it to populate your `TableView`:

```
tableView.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(persons));
```

Now, when your user clicks a `Button` or you otherwise want to update the `TableView` with a new value, you would update the `Person` object:

```
person.setEmail("me@home.com");
```

As soon as that property is changed, the `TableView` will update to reflect the new value.

---

This is a high-level overview/example.

Comment: Thank you Zephyr, I tryied another way and some how I managed to update my table view "Alhamdulillah". May be letter I will add the code here " Insh Allah".